# Adding a call to a method before a STFLD causes an InvalidProgramException

Tags: c#, jit, cil

I have access to a function body Intermediate Language like this :

```cs
byte[] ilCodes = NestedFooInfo.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
```

I want to be able to modify its IL code so that whenever there is a `stfld` IL command I call the following method named `OnChangeField`:

```cs
public static void OnChangeField(object obj, object value)
{
    Console.WriteLine("VICTORY");
    return;
}
```

So far I do it like this :

I define the call instruction to the method I want to call:

```cs
MethodInfo OnStfld = typeof(MethodBoundaryAspect).GetMethod("OnChangeField");
byte[] callIL = new byte[5];
callIL[0] = (byte)OpCodes.Call.Value;
callIL[1] = (byte)(OnStfld.MetadataToken & 0xFF);
callIL[2] = (byte)(OnStfld.MetadataToken >> 8 & 0xFF);
callIL[3] = (byte)(OnStfld.MetadataToken >> 16 & 0xFF);
callIL[4] = (byte)(OnStfld.MetadataToken >> 24 & 0xFF);
```

And I alter the original(`NestedFoo(...)`) method body code like this :

```cs
byte[] ilCodes = NestedFooInfo.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
var stfldOpCode = (byte)OpCodes.Stfld.Value;
for (int i = 0; i < ilCodes.Length; i++)
{
    if (ilCodes[i] == stfldOpCode)
    {
         byte[] newIlCodes = ilCodes.Take(i).Concat(callIL).Concat(ilCodes.Skip(i)).ToArray(); // Insert the call instruction before the s
         InjectionHelper.UpdateILCodes(NestedFooInfo, newIlCodes); // Explanation below
         break; // Currently I just want to hook the first stfld as a PoC
     }
}
```

The method body altered in my test case is this :

```cs
public class ExceptionHandlingService : IExceptionHandlingService
{
        public static string var1 = "initialValue";
        public static string Var2 { get; set; } = "initialValue";
        public string var3 = "initialValue";
        public string Var4 { get; set; } = "initialValue";

        public string NestedFoo(SampleClass bar)
        {
            var1 = "value set in NestedFoo()";
            Var2 = "value set in NestedFoo()";
            var3 = "value set in NestedFoo()";
            Var4 = "value set in NestedFoo()";
            AddPerson("From", "NestedFoo", 2);
            return Foo();
        }
        [...]
}
```

I call the method like this :

```cs
var a = new ExceptionHandlingService();
var b = new SampleClass("bonjour", 2, 3L); // Not really relevant
a.NestedFoo(b);
```

And i get a :

> System.InvalidProgramException: 'Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.'

or a

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'Index not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131124)'

If I remove postsharp and the services Interface from `ExceptionHandlingService`

I suppose that I edited the Il code in a way that lead to an invalid codeflow but looking at the `call` and `stfld` documentation [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) (p368 and p453) I don't know what I did wrong.

For those who wonder what magic happens in
`InjectionHelper.UpdateILCodes(NestedFooInfo, newIlCodes);` you can check [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/NET-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Code-during-Run-time) which shows how you can edit Il code at runtime.

Comment: Can you show an example of a sample input IL stream along with how you want the final IL to look like after your injection? I ask because it isn't altogether clear what the final IL would look like. In particular I am wondering about where you get the parameter values to your call to `OnChangeField` from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IL is a bit fragile, it's not really meant to be assembled by hand :) In any case, you can't find `stfld` just by looking for a single byte value - you need to make sure you're actually reading an opcode, and not an argument etc.

If you don't have an overriding reason not to, I'd recommend using `Expression` trees to compile the "raw" IL - that should save you a lot of headache. Regardless, try to move by very small steps - e.g. first try injecting a call at the start of the method, try a method with no arguments, then try finding `stfld`, handle the more complicated cases (boxing etc.)...

To move forward, it helps to use compilers and decompilers. Compile normal C# code calling your method, and decompile it into IL. Try the injection, and decompile the resulting full IL byte array - you'll likely find the mistake (though I wouldn't say "easily enough", since it needs a bit of IL experience to spot most mistakes :)).

One thing that jumps out on the spot is that you're keeping both the `stfld` and the `call`, but only passing the arguments once. Again, as part of identifying the issue, it helps to do things one at a time - replace the `stfld` with the `call` to make sure that part works; then deal with `dup`ing the values on the stack to allow you to invoke both operations.

Answer (score 1):

The following exception was caused by the metadata token of the OnChangeField() method which was outsite the executing assembly.

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'Index not found. (Exception from
> HRESULT: 0x80131124)'

And the  following exception was caused by a postsharp aspect beeing applied to the NestedFoo function but also because I didn't push any argument on the stack to be passed to OnchangeField arguments:

> System.InvalidProgramException: 'Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.'